# How to weatherproof this window?

Tags: windows, weatherstripping

[image]

Check the picture of this window. During winter months, caulking (horizontal red arrow) and vertical red arrow where there is trim, gets extremely cold. I can even feel some air draft.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove old caulk.
2. Remove trim.
3. Use expanding foam to fill the gap between the window and the rough opening. Make sure to use the foam that is made for windows, otherwise the expanding foam can bend the window frame.
4. Replace all trim pieces and caulk with latex-based caulk.
5. Add new silicone-based caulk around window.

Comment: +1. Can you provide more detail on steps 4 & 5. Where does the silicone v latex caulk go? Inside/outside? Which is which?